# Is it possible to have $\xi$ and $\chi$ independent?

Tags: probability

**Problem:**

> Random variables $\xi$ and $\eta$ are independent and equally
> Bernoulli-distributed. Let $\chi$ be the indicator that their sum is an
> odd number. Is it possible to have $\xi$ and $\chi$ independent?

**Solution:**

*Let $\xi,\eta\sim\text{Bern}(p)$ for some $p\in (0,1)$. The sum $\xi+\eta$ then has $\text{Bin}(2,p)$ distribution and thus $\chi\sim\text{Bern}(2p(1-p))$. If $\xi=0$ and $\xi+\eta$ is odd, then $\eta=1$ so that $\{\xi=0,\chi=0\}$ happens with probability $(1-p)^2$. Similar reasoning gives $\Pr(\xi=1,\chi=0)=p^2,$ and $\Pr(\xi=0,\chi=1)=\Pr(\xi=1,\chi=1)=p(1-p)$.*

*For independence we must have in particular that $\Pr(\xi=1,\chi=1)=\Pr(\xi=1)\Pr(\chi = 1)$, i.e. $p(1-p)=p\cdot 2p(1-p)$ which is uniquely solved by $p=1/2$. Doing this for the rest of the combinations of outcomes gives the same result.*

**Question:**

I do understand most of the solution except when it's concluded that $\chi\sim\text{Bern}(2p(1-p))$. I don't think I'm sure how the indicator is supposed to tie into this. Does it mean that $\chi=1$ if $\xi+\eta=\text{odd}$ and $\chi=0$ else? If someone could inject some intuition to this I'd be thankful.

Comment: Did you mean "let $\chi$ be the indicator...", not "let $\xi$ be the indicator..."?

Comment: Absolutely, I'm so sorry about that. Edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
\xi & \eta & \xi + \eta & \chi & \text{Probability}\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & (1-p)^2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & p(1-p) \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & p(1-p) \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & p^2 \\
\end{array}$$
Therefore, if $\xi$ and $\chi$ are independent, we would have in particular $$\Pr[\chi = 1 \cap \xi = 1] = \Pr[\chi = 1]\Pr[\xi = 1].$$  Is this true?

Comment: Can you explain how you calculated the probabilities? And as an answer to your question, it's true iff $p=1/2$.

Comment: @Parseval The probability depends only on the values of the first two columns because the third and fourth columns are uniquely determined by the first two.  Since $\xi$ and $\eta$ are IID Bernoulli variables, with $\Pr[\xi = 1] = \Pr[\eta = 1] = p$, then the probability column is simply the product of the individual probabilities of each outcome; e.g., for the fourth row, $\Pr[\xi = 1 \cap \eta = 1] = \Pr[\xi = 1] \Pr[\eta = 1] = p^2$.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $S = \zeta + \eta \sim \text{Bin}(2, p)$.

Now
$$\mathbb{P}(S \text{ is odd}) = \mathbb{P}(S = 1) =  \binom{2}{1}p(1-p) = 2p(1-p)\text{.}$$
Thus, $$\chi = \mathbf{I}(S \text{ is odd}) = \begin{cases}
1, & S\text{ is odd} \\
0, & \text{otherewise}
\end{cases}$$  follows a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $\mathbb{P}(\chi = 1) = \mathbb{P}(S \text{ is odd}) = 2p(1-p)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though I still don't see why the parameter of the Bernoulli distribution of $\chi$ is $\chi=1$.